# The c++ 20 way to parse a simple delimited string

Tags: c++, c++20

There are plenty of questions and answers here on how to parse delimited strings. I am looking for c++20 ish answers. The following works, but it feels lacking. Any suggestions to do this more elegantly?

```
const std::string& n = "1,2,3,4";
const std::string& delim = ",";
std::vector<std::string> line;
for (const auto& word : std::views::split(n, delim)) {
    line.push_back(std::string(word.begin(), word.end()));
    }
```

Comment: This looks like it might be better suited to [codereview.se], but check their help before posting.

Comment: This isn't the answer you're looking for, but `line.emplace_back(word.begin(), word.end())` is better because an `emplace`-like-function constructs the object directly in the spot in the vector instead of constructing a `string` object then copying it into the vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create substrings of type `std::string`, you can use `std::string_view` to avoid unnecessary memory allocation.
With the introduction of C++23 [`ranges::to`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.utility.conv.to), this can be written as

```
const std::string& n = "1,2,3,4";
const std::string& delim = ",";
const auto line = n | std::views::split(delim)
                    | std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string_view>>();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6dvvbno8W)